# How to schedule job in Jenkins every 4 hours and 10 minutes

Tags: jenkins

I made jobs to start at every 4 hours `H */4 * * *`
But I can't schedule at 4:10
I tried `10 */4 * * *` and `H/10 */4 * * *`
Unfortunately no luck

Answer (score 4):

Configuring a fixed time is very simple:

```
10 4 * * *
```

Your `10 */4 * * *` means "run it every 4 hours, at minute 10".

See also http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/ for reference.

## EDIT

Sorry, from the description it seems you want to run it at *exactly* 4.10, but I then realized that in the title you say something different: every 4h and 10'. Do you mean e.g. at [1.10, 5.20, 9.30]? If so, try `*/10 */4 * * *`.

Please provide an example with a sequence of times you expect, e.g. [2.10, 3.20, 4.30], so that it's more clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I would like to run it every 4:10, e.g. 1:02, 5:12, 9:22, etc. When I try `*/10 */4 * * *` there is a message Spread load evenly by using ‘H/10 */4 * * *’ rather than ‘*/10 */4 * * *’

Comment: Well, that's just an advice, you don't have to follow it, generally speaking. But I think you should, as it should fit your needs, as far as I understand. `*/10` means `X:(0+10*n)`, i.e. [X:00, X:10, X:20 .. X:50]. While `H/10 */4` means `X:(Y+10*n)`, where Y is decided by the system, i.e. [X:Y, X:(Y+10), X:(Y+20), ..]. The point is: you don't know at what minute it will run, but you know that it will run "every 10 minutes". See also http://bit.ly/1vma0lZ